# What is "current rating" in a battery implied by?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

How battery limits current to the maximum level that is indicated in its specification? If V/R value is greater than maximum current rating then current through the device will be V/R or maximum current rating of battery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if the battery has a protection mechanism or not. For instance, Lithium-based batteries can be dangerous if the discharge current is too high, and require protection mechanisms to guarantee safety. Cheap batteries can be found without such mechanisms, but they represent an hazard and can be illegal.

In some cases, due to internal resistance the output voltage will drop depending on the current that is drawn, therefore limiting the maximum current that can be obtained.

You might find [this page at Battery University](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/safety_circuits_for_modern_batteries) interesting.

Comment: I posted that question before you put this link here. Last time when I asked my doubt as a comment moderator asked me to put it as another question. That is why I put second question. Now here I got something to explore from your link. I will go through it now. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @tollinjose nothing personal, I just wanted to point out that many times the answer is already there, it just takes a small search. The linked site is a good source anyway, give it a look.

Comment: here too :). I asked this when I got stuck. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

"Current rating" always refers to the maximum *allowed* current. It is the responsibility of the user of the device to make sure that the current stays withing this limit.

The device in question might limit the current in some way, but in most cases that limit will be a sort of be a second level defense, and its current will be higher than the current rating.

This holds for batteries, digital output pins, voltage regulators, etc. etc.